# Split string into associative array by multiple delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, string

From the following string:

"`I am looking for {{ attribute_a }} with {{ attribute_b }} to make {{ attribute_c }}`":

I am trying to create the following array structure:

```
[
   [0] => [
      "type" => "text", 
      "content" => "I am looking for"
   ], 
   [1] => [
      "type" => "dropdown", 
      "name" => "attribute_a"
   ], 
   [2] => [
      "type" => "text",
      "content" => "with"
   ],
   [3] => [
      "type" => "dropdown", 
      "name" => "attribute_b"
   ], 
   [4] => [
      "type" => "text",
      "content" => "to make"
   ],
   [5] => [
      "type" => "dropdown", 
      "name" => "attribute_c"
   ]
]
```

So the string needs to be cut into parts with "{{ * }}" as a delimiter. But then I need the value inside the delimiter too.

- If the part is outside the delimiter it is a type of text with content.
- If it is inside the delimiter it is a type of dropdown with a property of the name.

Comment: What you've described is a task, not a problem

Comment: @Cid Okay, Let me add with I tried thus far.

Comment: preg_split with delimiter capture

Comment: @YourCommonSense but how do I capture the non-delimiter parts then?

Comment: You don't need to capture those, those become part of the result array on their own.

Comment: @CBroe okay thanks. I am gonna look into it! preg_split( $pattern, $structure, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

Comment: Pattern `#(\{\{[^}]*\}\})#` + PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE gets you `I am looking for[space]`, `{{ attribute_a }}`, `[space]with[space]`, etc. You can then check if each individual value is surrounded by `{{...}}` to determine its "type". Trim off the extra spaces from the other values, if you don't want them.

Comment: @CBroe thank you! Now I think I can figure it out :)

Comment: @Robbert your string looks like Twig format, did you try with a proper parser?

Comment: @Cid you are right. Not did not try a parser yet, but created a solution already (below) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Your Common Sense and CBroe I figured it out:

```
$result = [];
$pattern = '/(\{\{[^}]*\}\})/';
$lines = preg_split( $pattern, $structure, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
   foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
      preg_match( $pattern, $line, $matches );
      if ( $matches ) {
         $result[] = [
            'type' => 'dropdown',
            'name' => trim( str_replace( ['{{', '}}'], "", $line ) )
         ]; 
      } else {
         $result[] = [
            'type' => "text",
            'content' => trim( $line )
         ];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `preg_match_all` is enough if no syntax errors are to be handled.

```
$result=[];
if( preg_match_all('~(\{\{[^\}]+\}\})|([^{}]+)~u',$structure,$match) ){
  foreach($match[0] as $item){
    $text = trim($item," {}\r\n");
    $result[] = strpos($item,"{{") !== false
      ? ["type" => "dropdown", "name" => $text]
      : ["type" => "text", "content" => $text] 
    ;
  }
}
```